# Parsing a string 'Ba1 Cl2 O8' to get two separate tuples of ints and strings

Tags: python, string, parsing, tuples

I have a string of a chemical formula: `'Ba1 Cl2 O8'`. I need to parse the string into two seperate tuples like the following:

```
comp = ('Ba','Cl','O')
count = (1,2,8)
```

The code needs to work for any formula with arbitrary length and with a count of more than one digit eg. `'H2 O1'`, `'Ba11 Sn7 O16'`

Comment: is the numbers at the end of each string only 1 digit?

Comment: No I could have a formula say `'Ba2 Sn1 O16'`, I didn't realize that

Answer (score 1):

Solution with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```py
from itertools import groupby

s = "Ba11 Sn7 O16"

comp, count = [], []
for v, g in groupby(s, str.isdigit):
    (count if v else comp).append("".join(g).strip())

print(tuple(comp))
print(tuple(map(int, count)))
```

Prints:

```py
('Ba', 'Sn', 'O')
(11, 7, 16)
```

Comment: This is an incredibly interesting solution. I really like the use of the ternary here!

Answer (score 0):

I would use regex for that

```
import re
text = 'Ba2 Sn1 O16'
comp  = re.findall(r"[A-Z][a-z]*", text)
nums = re.findall(r"[0-9]+", text)
count = [int(x) for x in nums]
print(tuple(comp ))
print(tuple(count))
```

output:

```
('Ba', 'Sn', 'O')
(2, 1, 16)
```

Comment: actually `count` it's a tuple of numbers

Answer (score 0):

Given this example  'H2 O1', 'Ba11 Sn7 O16' you have several layers of the onion to peal.
Assuming this is read a single line of text. Watch out for trailing newlines
use rstrip()

The item separated at commas, Use line.split(',') and strip to get rid of blanks.
This will give you a list of quoted items.
Iterating on this list you have to remove the quotes.
A slice of elements[1,-1] a
This is optional but leaving it out would make later steps more complex.

Now you have to split on the spaces between elements.

Finally you have a list of elements which have the pattern  of 1 or 2 letters followed by a number.  This can be done with the regular expression
functions.  This is a topic of study on its own.

The alternative at this step is to process the element character by character. Simple concept but could be messy code.

Text manipulation/parsing can be messy because you have to account for imperfect inputs.  There is a lot of attention to details like how many space are entered into the string and are symbols used multiple times.

If this is not oblivious there are 3 level of nesting in these loops.
1 Split on commas 2 remove quotes and split on spaces 3 Split on the pattern.
It would be good to perfect each level before you go to the inner ones.

Ohad Sharet answer shows a regular expression that would handle the 2 inner loops.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possibly more direct regular expression-based solution.

It starts with the regular expression:

```py
import re
atom_count = re.compile(r"(\w+)(\d+)")
```

That regular expression could be made more precise. One possibility might be `r"([A-Z][a-z]?)([1-9][0-9]*)"`. It depends, at least in part, on what you consider a valid input, and what you want to do if you get something which is not valid. The important thing is that it has two captures, one for the atom and one for the count.

With that pattern, `atom_count.findall` will produce a list of tuples, each one containing an element and a count:

```
>>> atom_count.findall('Ba2 Sn1 O16')
[('Ba', '2'), ('Sn', '1'), ('O', '16')]
```

But you want two lists, one containing element names, and the other containing counts. In effect, that's the inverse of what `zip` does, and there's a standard python idiom for inverting `zip`:

```py
def unzip(list_of_tuples):
    """Takes something which might be the result of calling zip, and
       breaks it down into the lists which might have been zipped."""
    return list(zip(*list_of_tuples))
```

This depends on the "unpacking" syntax (unary `*`),  sometimes called the "splat operator",  which takes an iterable turns it into individual function arguments (or list values).  Used with `zip`, that has the effect of transposing a list of lists:

```
>>> list(zip(*(('one', 1, 'a'), ('two', 2, 'b'), ('three', 3, 'c'))))
[('one', 'two', 'three'), (1, 2, 3), ('a', 'b', 'c')]
```

That's precisely the transformation needed to turn the result of `findall` into two lists:

```py
import re
atom_count = re.compile(r"(\w+)(\d+)")
def parse_compound(s):
    return tuple(zip(*atom_count.findall(s)))
```

Example:

```
>>> parse_compound('Ba2 Sn1 O16')
(('Ba', 'Sn', 'O'), ('2', '1', '16'))
```